# yii database host check

Tags: mysql, database, yii

How can I check whether database host is valid?

```
  try {
     Yii::app()->db;
  } catch (Exception $ex) {
     echo $ex->getMessage();
  }
```

Code above gives me this error when I use invalid host address:

```
PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
```

I just want to receive something that returns false, so I could display my own error message

Comment: do you have the arguments for the database in the right place?

Comment: yes I just used invalid host on purpose

Comment: have you try `mysql_ping `?

Comment: @jycr753 it says "mysql_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known" when I tried to connect using mysql_connect, don't see anything helpful in link you provided